# GWT with pure js/html UI

Tags: java, gwt, web

We are using GWT in our Web Java project for implementing client UI and client business logics. We've chosen it because it's really convenient to write everything in Java (and thus avoid duplicated business objects). Brief exploration of GWT docs/tutorials/blogs showed that it has built-in support for css, i18n, all browsers and has its own marking html-like language (uibinder).

So we've chosen GWT and everything was OK until we've decided to outsource front-end development.

1. It's really hard to find experienced front-end freelancer with GWT knowlenge, so we have to ask them to develop html+js code and then we convert it into GWT .ui.xml pages by ourselves. It's very error-prone and routine.
2. GWT generates html itself, therefore applying css-s revealed to be really tough issue. GWT creates additional div-s, tables and so on. Resulting html looks really ugly - something is 2 pixels to the left of expected position, something 3 pixels to the right and so on.

So now we are thinking of rewriting al UI in pure js+html and using GWT only for client business logic and client-server interaction.

The question is: are there any libs/frameworks for simplifying dealing with js elements from GWT?
And the second one is kinda ritoric question to the community: maybe somebody faced similar problems and can help with advice?

Thanks! Vitaly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at Errai:

http://erraiframework.org/

and here:

https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/ERRAI/Errai+UI#ErraiUI-Createa@TemplatedCompositecomponent

With Errai you can use native HTML with GWT.

Hope it helps.